# Why does IntelliJ IDEA rebuilds indexes when the sources haven't change?

Tags: performance, intellij-idea, ide

It looks like the indexing starts whenever I reopen the IDE of IntelliJ 14 Enterprise. Indexing blocks me from using e.g. Text Search, thus slowing me down.

Anyone has good tips how to get the my work going smoother?

Comment: Does this happen *every* time?  Are you sure that something isn't changing (Maven/Gradle dependencies, something from source control)?

Comment: Every time, I suppose. Perhaps IDEA is generating something each time after start, as it scans the files. But it's still weird to block actions while rebuilding...

Comment: That is strange.  I can't diagnose it myself since I'm not a Jetbrains employee (but they do lurk around here).  Could you include your system specs in the question, like your OS, type of hard disk, memory, and CPU?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because of an exception thrown by some plugin. You can see the details of the exception in the log (Help | Show Log).